# Missing ) after argument list syntax error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, syntax, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to make a script that creates a new tab based on data submitted from a form and inserts a formula into the new tab on creation. The last line of the script is giving me a syntax error. "Missing ) after argument list". All parenthesis seem to be closed properly. Am I missing something?

```
function makeTabs() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var last = sheet.getLastRow();
  for(var i=0; i<last; i++){
    var tabName = sheet.getRange(i+1,1).getValue();
    var create = ss.insertSheet(tabName);
    var tab = ss.getRange('A2').activate();
    var tab = ss.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=QUERY(\'Form Responses 1\'!A2:R,"select * where C="'tabName'",-1)")');
  }
}
```

Comment: Your variable is outside of quotes, and you are not preforming any operation on it. Change to this `... C=" + tabName + " ...`

Comment: This helped a lot. It got the tabName into the document. I did need to add extra quotes in to make sure that the Query ran on the front end: `C=""' +tabName+ '"""`

Comment: check your 'tabName' in setformula expression

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `tabName` is a String, it should be single quote enclosed on the Google Sheets side. Also use `+` to concatenate on the Google Apps Script side

Replace

```
'=QUERY(\'Form Responses 1\'!A2:R,"select * where C="'tabName'",-1)")'
```

by

```
'=QUERY(\'Form Responses 1\'!A2:R,"select * where C=\'"' + tabName + '\'",-1)")'
```

By the other hand, bear in mind that the Best Practices discourage the use of Apps Script read/write methods inside of loops

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in the last statement where you are concatenating two strings with `tabName` between. String concatenation can be performed with the `+` operator, like this:

```
'=QUERY(\'Form Responses 1\'!A2:R,"select * where C="' + tabName + '",-1)")'
```

The error is received because without an operator to signify an operation or a comma to signify an additional argument, it's expecting to see the close of the function with `)`.